# PHP get class var in foreach

Tags: php, class, foreach

I'm trying to retrieve the value from a public function from a class into a `foreach`.

`$class->function()` is passing an array and I want to scan each value.

```
 foreach($class->function() as $key => $index) {
     $class->function()[$key];
```

The strange thing is that this code on `localhost` is working correctly, but on my server online is giving this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Besides checking the versions of PHP that you're running to ensure that the server version supports array dereferencing (>=5.4), why not actually use your $index value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the result of function to some variable:

```
$result = $class->function();
foreach($result as $key => $index) {
    echo $result[$key];
}
```

However `$result[$key]` is equals to `$index` FYI;

This kind of access value directly from function call is available since `PHP 5.4`.

Comment: Thank's a lot, it was really simple!